# Is there a difference between a field and a function?

Tags: field-theory, terminology

Any field (in the physics sense of the word) is a function.

But is any function a field? It seems that one might construct a function that returns a tuple consisting of $6$, temperature and electric potential. We would not consider that a field, right? So where is the line?

Basically I am looking for a decent definition of the term **field**.

Comment: This post talks about what a field is. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/364358/37364

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13157/

Answer (score 3):

The following definition i borrowed from a QFT lecture by Tobias Osborne.

A field $\phi$ is a quantity (e.g. density, space, charge, ...) defined at
every point in a manifold $\mathcal M$ (spacetime).
So for us the manifold is often $\mathcal M = \mathbb R _t \times \mathbb R ^3 _{\vec{r}} $. The field $\phi$ is then a function

$$ \phi: \mathcal M \rightarrow \mathcal S $$

where $\mathcal S$ is a target-space. For example $\mathcal S = \mathbb R$ which would be a scalar field like temperature. Or $\mathcal S = \mathbb R^3$ would be a vector field like the electric field. Usually a field $\phi$ should be at least two times differentiable.