# Is light *nothing more* than a pair of transverse electric and magnetic oscillating field moving in a given direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

If one creates an oscillating electric field and a magnetic field, transversal to each other, and oscillating at a given frequency belonging to the visible spectrum, and moving in a given direction of an observator, will an observer see the same as compared to the same experiment where he looks at the light ?

Said differently, is light nothing more than a pair of transverse electric and magnetic fields?
So would creating a pair of transverse electric and magnetic oscillating fields moving in a given direction be equivalent to create light?

Comment: The mechanism you propose is one of the ways light is generated.

Comment: Sure, but but look at the detail of my paraph for the question.

Comment: It is not clear where you think the possible difference between "light" and "just an electromagnetic wave" lies.

Comment: you will see light if the frequency is within the visible light spectrum

Comment: "...moving in a given direction of an observator, will an observer see the same as compared to the same experiment where he looks at the light ?"  What's the difference between these two observers?

Comment: @garyp - He means that one creates these fields so they move toward the observer.

Comment: The question assumes we're in the realm of classical physics. There is *something more* when we put the question in the quantum mechanical world.

Comment: @mmesser314 How does that differ from "looking at the light"?  Or perhaps what does he mean by "observe" in the first case?

Comment: @garyp - That is the question he is asking. The answer is that it doesn't differ.

Comment: @mmesser314 : Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be hard to say what light really is. You are talking about the classical view of light. Descheleschilder's answer is correct. But if you look at a microscopic view of light, you need quantum mechanics.

This is like looking at what air pressure is. In a large scale view (classical), it is a smooth force that air exerts on the walls. But microscopically, it isn't smooth. It is individual air molecules bouncing off the wall. Each molecule gives the wall an individual kick. When you add up lots of these kicks, you get a smooth force. It is really the same explanation, but it looks totally different.

Light is the same. On a microscopic scale, light can be emitted by an individual electron in an atom, and absorbed by another electron in another atom. One atom gives another a kick. When you add up lots of atoms, you can see a smooth force that is described by an electromagnetic field.

An individual atom's worth of light has a name "photon", but that doesn't say what light is. A photon is sort of like a particle and sort of like a wave. For more on that, see my answer to [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364).

It can also get confusing if you take a careful look at the classical picture. What kind of thing is an electric field? See my answer to [In what medium are non-mechanical waves a disturbance? The aether?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/364358/37364)

Comment: The question isn't about quantum mechanics but about classic(al) electrodynamics. It's a good reading though!

Answer (score 2):

An oscillating electric field and magnetic field propagates as light and Heinrich Hertz has already demonstrated that by creating radio waves in the laboratory.

So yes light is a pair of transverse oscillating electric and magnetic fields.

Comment: check the question "nothing more than".

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing more"? Maxwell's electromagnetic theory is sufficient to account for the wave nature of light. As far as the particle nature goes that does not discard the wave nature so in essence light is *pair of transverse oscillating electric and magnetic fields.*

Comment: ok : so if in a laboratory, I create a transverse electric and magnetic oscillating fields moving in a given direction : will we see light ?

Comment: Yes. If the frequency is within the visible spectrum. You do see light out of a light bulb don't you? What do you think causes that?

Comment: ok thank you @Lost

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: **So would creating a pair of transverse electric and magnetic oscillating fields moving in a given direction be equivalent to create light?**, to which the answer is "no".

Comment: @descheleschilder The answer is "yes".

Comment: @descheleschilder: I have given the answer by referring to the Hertz experiment which clearly implies that E-M waves can be and have been created in the Lab. Visible light is nothing unique and can be created similarly. So the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

To the question "is light nothing more than a pair of transverse electric and magnetic fields?" the answer is: "classically yes, indeed". However, these fields are a wave function, like Schrödinger's equation, that describes the probability of finding photons, the massless point particles that light consists of.

Comment: +1. I see the point of your comment to my answer now.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. **However these fields are a wave function, like Schrodinger's, that describes the probability of finding photons** This simply not true. The fields are **not** wavefunctions. They have the **form** of a wave. There are mathematical expressions tough that give a description of these waves. These can derived from Maxwell's equations.

Comment: So we meet again. I am sorry to have to tell you that you are again wrong, @descheleschilder. The famous two slit experiment with very low intensity proved that the classical intensity is to be interpreted as the probability of detecting a photon.

Comment: You seriously must try (read!) to get some understanding of what classical and quantum physics are about. Read some books, or read online. It's what **I** did! Classical electromagnetics, of course, can explain the interference pattern. There is no need to interpreter it in a quantum mechanical way. It's **how** the pattern is formed where quantum mechanics kicks in: Dot, dot, dot...

Comment: @descheleschilder what my2cts is saying is that classical electrodynamics is an average behaviour of the more accurate quantum description. If the double slit experiment is conducted with sufficiently low intensity, then classical electrodynamics fails to explain the “dot, dot...”

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish **an average behavior of the more accurate quantum description.** What exactly do you mean with that?

Comment: Fields can entirely be described by charge and current distributions (Jefimenko’s equations). So under quantum mechanics, one replaces those with expectation of charge and current distributions. So the theory is accurate only on average. But if we have enough resolution to resolve between each event then we see quantum properties, like the low intensity double slit experiment.

Comment: No. Under quantum mechanics (QED) one assumes the basic unit of an e.m. wave is a photon. You construct the Lagrangian corresponding to the wave-equation for charged particles (the Dirac equation), after which you make the assumption that the Lagrangian has to stay invariant under local gauge transformations. When doing this the four-vector $A_{\mu}$ joins the game which corresponds to the photon field. It's quite difficult to distill the classical wave from photons.

Comment: The classical intensity doesn't represent an average. It's just an intensity, already worked out before the advent of QED.

Comment: @descheleschilder 
"the basic unit of an e.m. wave is a photon" This statement is not mainstream physics, which holds that a photon is a massless point particle.

Comment: @descheleschilder "The classical intensity doesn't represent an average." The classical intensity gives the probability density. This is validated by the famous low intensity experiments.

Comment: @my2cts: Wave functions are solutions to the Schrodinger wave equation while E-M waves are solutions of the classical wave equation derived from Maxwell's equations. Hence they are not same.

Comment: @Lost I agree until "hence". Experiment is on my side. Also, Maxwell's equations are essentially massless wave equations, like the Klein-Gordon equation with m=0.

Comment: my2cts: Please state which experimental indicate that E-M waves are matter waves.

Comment: Also Schrodinger's Differential Equation is different than Maxwell's where the there is an iota with the *first derivative of time* giving complex solns as opposed to Maxwell's wave equation which is identical to the classical wave equation where there are no complex contributions and *is in second order with respect to time* , the solution of which give real vector fields.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way you can create classical light waves. Both the electric and magnetic fields can't be made to vary in time independently.
It's the easiest just to let an electric field vary periodically in time at visible light frequencies. The magnetic field will automatically be created, according to Maxwell's equations.

A varying magnetic field would also create an electromagnetic wave, but that's much harder to realize because there is much less energy contained in a magnetic field.

In both cases (creating the varying fields) an electromagnetic wave will emerge.

So the answer is: No.

Comment: Wait. I’m with you till the last line. Why do you say no and how is it implied from your previous statements?

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish **So would creating a pair of transverse electric and magnetic oscillating fields moving in a given direction be equivalent to create light?**. It's impossible to create a pair of oscillating fields. You either create an oscillating electric field **or** an oscillating magnetic field (which is more difficult). In both separate cases, there will appear an e.m. wave. When you create an oscillating magnetic field and an oscillating electric field you can't just put them together to create such a wave.

Comment: Whatever fields we create obeys Maxwell’s equations. So if we have an oscillating charge source, it would create *a pair of transverse electric and magnetic oscillating fields moving in a given direction*. And yes. That is equivalent to light (em wave).

Comment: That is not what is asked. The OP is under the impression one can create two fields, a periodically varying magnetic field and the same kind of an electric field, independently from each other. Then you put these two waves together and behold, we have created an e.m. wave. I think he doesn't realize that it takes only **one** of both to create an oscillating e.m. wave.

Comment: Perhaps OP is under that impression and your answer clarifies the error. But I still don’t understand what the “no” in your answer is referring to. OP has 3 statements with a question mark. So what are you saying no to. Due to this confusion I voted -1

Comment: I said no to his last question: **So would creating a pair of transverse electric and magnetic oscillating fields moving in a given direction be equivalent to create light?**

Comment: @descheleschilder:'In both cases (creating the varying fields) an electromagnetic wave will emerge.' And then writing 'no' to  the question asked is contradictory.

Comment: @Lost I just stated that in the case of an oscillating electric field an e.m. wave will emerge (containing the two transverse waves) as well as in the case of an oscillating magnetic field. But OP thinks an electromagnetic wave can be made out of two independent oscillating fields: one magnetic and one electric, at two different places.  **So would creating a pair of transverse electric and magnetic oscillating fields moving in a given direction be equivalent to create light?**  I think OP wants to **create** an oscillating e.m. field by superimposing the two. No contradiction.