# Questions regarding light being depicted as a sine wave

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

Light waves are often depicted as sine waves...
Why is it so?

What's actually waving?

And what does the sine wave signify and represent?
[image]

What does wavelength of light mean/signify? and how is it calculated for specific colors?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Thank you! but this doesn't answer all my queries...I'm looking for a simple and detailed answer...

Comment: @LuciferP - 'simple' and 'detailed' contradict each other much of the time.

Comment: Does this answer some part of your question? - [In what medium are non-mechanical waves a disturbance? The aether?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/364358/37364)

Comment: The electric and magnetic field change in amplitude with a frequency. The figure you supplied shows the wavelength as the bar measured between two points of constant phase, in this case the peaks of the wave. The ratio of wavelength to frequency is the speed of light. But really numerous YouTube and wikipedia pages and textbooks have whole pages at all levels of sophistication that walk you through this electromagnetic waves.

Comment: Electric and magnetic fields are [waving](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Onde_electromagnetique.svg).

Comment: How is the wavelength for specific colors like red or violet calculated?

Comment: How "color" corresponds to a given wavelength of light is more of a subjective question than an objective one, and a lot of it depends on how the human eye responds to light of various wavelengths.  The wavelength for a specific color can't be "calculated" without making some simplifying assumptions about the nature of the light and how the human eye works.  There is *definitely* not a "simple and detailed" answer for that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture is very missleading. What is waving is an electric field and a magnetic field, therefor we call it an electromagnetic wave. the different colors have different wavelength, which is the distance of two consecutive maxima of the electric field. but the wavelength is so short, one can not really depict it, it is less than $\frac{1}{100000}mm$ but the kind of wave is just the same as the radio waves .

Answer (score 3):

Light is an electromagnetic wave. Under certain conditions, Maxwell's equations in a given region admit a solution of the form $\vec{E}=\vec{E}_0\cos(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\omega t),\,\vec{B}=\vec{B}_0\cos(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\omega t+\varphi)$.

In the direction of the **wavevector** $\vec{k}$, this solution propagates with **wavenumber** $k:=|\vec{k}|$, **wavelength** $\lambda:=2\pi/k$, **frequency** $\omega=ck/n$ for **refractive index** $n$ (*in vacuo* $n=1$) and **phase velocity** $v_g:=\omega/k=c/n$.

This isn't the only solution; one can [superpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle#Wave_superposition) them. An envelope of such waves of various $\omega,\,\vec{k}$ has [**group velocity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) $v_p:=\frac{\partial\omega}{\partial k}$ (you can show $v_p=cn=\frac{c^2}{v_g}$).